# spring security Remember Me logut doesn't clear cookie

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

(My english is not so good, but I will try my best to explain my question clearly.)

I just want use Remember Me with Spring Security, so I followed the steps as it mentioned in the Spring Security Reference.

Here is my code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @Autowired
    RoleMapper roleMapper;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/frame/**", "/img/**", "/css/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAt(myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login_page")).and()
                .addFilterAt(rememberMeAuthenticationFilter(), RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login_page")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/signout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login_page").permitAll().and()
                // .rememberMe().key("testallKey").and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl()).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder()).and()
                .authenticationProvider(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userMapper, roleMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myFilter = new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        myFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        myFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        myFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        myFilter.setRememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return myFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/login/success");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login/failure");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices tbrms = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("testallKey", userDetailsServiceImpl());
        tbrms.setTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 2);
        tbrms.setParameter("rememberMe");
        return tbrms;
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rmap = new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider("testallKey");
        return rmap;
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        RememberMeAuthenticationFilter myFilter = new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), tokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return myFilter;
    }

}
```

Remember me is fine, but when I logged out, it didn't clear the "remember-me" cookie automatically as it was supposed to.(So I have to use deleteCookies("remember-me") after logout() manually)

Anyone can tell me why it doesn't work?

And I found another apporach, it works:

if I use ".rememberMe().key("testallKey")" rather than add "rememberMeAuthenticationFilter" and "RememberMeAuthenticationProvider",, here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @Autowired
    RoleMapper roleMapper;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/frame/**", "/img/**", "/css/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterAt(myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login_page")).and()
                //.addFilterAt(rememberMeAuthenticationFilter(), RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login_page")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/signout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login_page").permitAll().and()
                .rememberMe().key("testallKey").and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl()).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userMapper, roleMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myFilter = new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        myFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        myFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
        myFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        myFilter.setRememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices());
        return myFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/login/success");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login/failure");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices tbrms = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("testallKey", userDetailsServiceImpl());
        tbrms.setTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 2);
        tbrms.setParameter("rememberMe");
        return tbrms;
    }


}
```

And can anyone tell me what's the difference between these two approaches?
(You can also point out my english grammar error ☺，thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use **.deleteCookies** in your configurer? also take a look at LogoutConfigurer documentation

```
http.logout()
.logoutSuccessUrl("/")
.logoutUrl("/logout")
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.permitAll();
```

[LogoutConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html)

Comment: yes, it woks. But like Spring Security Reference says  "TokenBasedRememberMeServices also implements Spring Security’s LogoutHandler interface so can be used with LogoutFilter to have the cookie cleared automatically." It should be cleared automatically, I want to know why it didn't. (approach 2 can clear it automatically)